# NoClassDefFound error

Tags: java, api, email

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
```

I have added the activator and mail jars to my server/deps directory, and am still encountering this problem and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you importing javax.mail.* ?

Comment: then where is the app deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind `NoClassDefFoundError` isn't the same as `ClassNotFoundException`. `NoClassDefFoundError` means that a class that was available in the classpath at compile time isn't available at runtime. Are you sure your jar files are in the *runtime* classpath?